# How to get sum of floats in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file containing a Persian sentence, then a tab, a Persian word, a tab and then an English word in each line of that. I also have a dictionary with keys and float values. I have to find the words of the file in each line that are in the dictionary, too. And then return their values. Then I have to calculate the logarithm of each word and finally calculate the sum of them for each line separately. The problem is, when I want to calculate the sum, this error occurs: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable. How can I fix it?

```
import math

probabilities = {"شور": 0.02, "نمک": 0.05,"زندگی": 0.07, "غذاهای": 0.01, "غذای": 0.05}

filename = "F.txt"

for line in open(filename, encoding="utf-8"):
    list_line = line.split("\t")
    words = list_line[0].split()
    for key, value in probabilities.items():
        for word in words:
            if word == key:
                result = sum(float(math.log(value)))
                print(word, result, end=" ")
    print()
```

When I run it, this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\example.py", line 14, in <module>
    result = sum(float(math.log(value)))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

F.txt ([https://www.dropbox.com/s/ag5at9iuuln2x02/F.txt?dl=0):

```
شور ورود دانشگاه جالب توجه  شور passion
۱۳ راهکار شور اشتیاق واقعی زندگی    شور passion
نمک موجود ذائقه غذاهای شور عادت شور salty
از مضرات نمک غذای شور بدانید    شور salty
```

I have to calculate the sum of each line separately and have just one number for each line at last.

Comment: can you [edit] your question so `probabilities` has standard characters and works? supsicious quotes everywhere => syntax error. And the rest of your code is wrong wrong wrong (actually every line is wrong, sorry!)

Comment: this is part of a bigger code. I summarized it here. so you can't say it's wrong. I just want to sum floats and it doesn't work just in that part.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre actually the code works, but is displayed incorrectly (at least in my browser) due to left-to-right language issues.  I cut-n-pasted the code and it does run and give the stated error.

Comment: That said, the `test(file1, file3)` part has no relevance to the code, and the question was edited to remove the link to the actual `F.txt` file input.  What is the **actual** desired output based on the `F.txt` input file?  Also, the `F.txt` file was useful.  I'll add it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very wrong indeed (you may skip to point #4):

1. your dictionary has syntax error with the quotes
2. you're splitting a *file handle* not lines
3. you create a double loop to search for keys when you already have a *dictionary*
4. you just need `result += float(math.log(value))`, (init `result` to 0 outside the loop) `sum` is for iterables.

Comment: look, this is a part of naive bayes algorithim. I have to find the words in sentences which are in dictionary, too. each sentence separately. Naturally, in some sentences there are more than one word. I have to get these words and calculate "sum" of them.

Comment: I edited the question. Can you write a new answer according to it. thank you